# why super is striked out in my project?

Tags: eclipse, robotium

I am using the below code:

why super is striked out ??

[image]

Comment: probably the same reason that ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 is underlined with that wavy yellow-orange line, you should handle any warnings in the order they appear, they might solve everything thereafter once fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also face the same problem,

i use bellow steps to solve this issue.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXuSZ.jpg) Remove all robotium package reference from your project.

[2] please try to add robotium package like i show in bellow image.
       - Just add "lib" folder in your package and add robotium-solo-3.4.1.jar file inside this folder.

[image: different method to add robotium package]

[3] "Clean" code from "Project" tool bar option in your eclipse editor.
and then see your code in eclipse, and it is work for me.

[4] and if possible then use eclipse latest version to run your projects.

i hope this will help you.

Comment: It is given that in the forum: ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2(String pkg, Class<T> activityClass). This constructor was deprecated in API level 8. 

use ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2(Class) instead....   shall i use Launcher_ActivityClass in place of Class.

Comment: hi, i am using API level 10 & please check http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumTutorials. if you cannot solve issue then please show your code. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That means the method is [deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation).  In this case, the developers have deprecated the constructor that takes those parameters.

In short, deprecation means that the developers of the library you're using have indicated that support for that particular method will not continue in the future.  In *most* cases, the method will still work as expected, but in future releases of the library it may not.

Comment: @Chandra sorry I confused this question iwth another one.  My comments were not helpful for you.  There's nothing you can do about it.  Ideally what you should do is try to find a different version of the constructor that is not deprecated.  Typically the developers will give you a hint as to which method you should use instead.

Comment: :The same thing is working on my colleague machine but i don't know why it is not working to me...

Comment: @Chandra you likely have a different version of the library.  To be clear, it doesn't mean that it won't work, it just means that you probably shouldn't rely on long term support for that particular method.  Please see the link I posted in my answer.